# Align 2 DIV per line, both the with the same height

Tags: html, css

We have a problem where we need to have a list of divs with dynamic content.
There will always be 2 divs per row. Both of those elements should have the same height.

Currently we have a solution which sets the height of the boxes with JavaScript, but it's not very performant, since it recalculates the sizes on every resize (Responsive design).

Is there a solution without fixed height values?

Important: The boxes still need to be padded, and the padding needs to be in percent (currently 4% margin on div)

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6dmwU/

```
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box" style="height: 203px;">
            <p class="box-title">Lorem Vulputate</p>
            <p>On corerias sunturero in cullabore dolestionet apid utatur On corerias sunturero in cullabore dolestionet apid utatur</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" style="height: 203px;">
            <p class="box-title">Egestas Pharetra</p>
            <p>On corerias sunturero in cullabore dolestionet apid utatur</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box" style="height: 151px;">
            <p class="box-title">Vulputate Egestas</p>
            <p>On corerias sunturero in cullabore dolestionet apid utatur</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" style="height: 151px;">
            <p class="box-title">Egestas Pharetra</p>
            <p>On corerias sunturero in cullabore dolestionet apid utatur</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: If using divs is not a requirement, how about a table?

Comment: Because of accessibility we should not use tables if there is any other way.

Comment: Your Fiddle shows al the div `.box` under each other. If I understand correctly, the both `.box` inside a `.box-wrapper` should be on one line...?

Comment: OT, but still relevant: You should use real list items instead of meaningless divs.

Comment: problem is in padding,margin because they takes 8% from 100% then how you give width:48% so reduce it add display:inline-block it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a flex model for this:

```
.boxes .box 
{
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 4%;
    border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
    border: 0.0625rem solid #b6b6b6;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box-wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

**[jsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dmwU/8/)**

This way every row will be the height of the highest child element.
However the support for this is limited.

So if you rather not use this method you can transform you structure in a table structure. This way every row will be the height of the highest child element.

```
.boxes .box 
{
    display: table-cell;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 4%;
    border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
    border: 0.0625rem solid #b6b6b6;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.box-wrapper
{
    display: table-row;
}

.boxes
{
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
```

Because margin doesn't work between table-cells i used `border-spacing` to define the seperation between the cells.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dmwU/10/)**

Comment: The first solution would be perfect, but it's not supported in IE9, which sadly is a requirement for this project.
The second solution uses border-spacing which does not allow percent based values, just pixel, em, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.boxes .box {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    width: 38%;
    padding: 4%;
    border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
    border: 0.0625rem solid #b6b6b6;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display:inline-block
}
.box-wrapper,.boxes{
        display:inline-block;
        width:100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dmwU/3/)

Comment: This does not address the requirement of no inline heights

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R2fmR/1/) You can use `display:table-cell;`

CSS:

```
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.left {
    width:50%;
    background: blue;
    display:table-cell;
}
.right {
    width:50%;
    background: red;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='left'>

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

    </div>
    <div class='right'>

"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos

    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: This is what we tried first, but you can't have a margin for the div's

Comment: You can mimic one by adding a border to one/all side(s) with the color set to the background

Answer (score 0):

I use flexbox, it's magic ^^ :

**HTML**

```
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
   margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
   width: 48%;
}
```

**[CODEPEN DEMO](https://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/agvmPv)**

Complete guide to flexbox on **[css-trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**